# Why response.data is undefined?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am fetching data using an API in react native. When fetched data in console, its successfully getting data. But while using the code below, the album array is showing undefined.

```js
state = { albums: [] };
 componentWillMount() {
    //fetch('https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=881262b246e1d3f2abda8771b1a25fe3&format=json')
 fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
  .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data     }));
}
```

I am getting console logs like this

{albums: Array(0)}

{albums: undefined}

Why this is undefined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) has no `data` property. You access the body of the response by calling the [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob), or [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) methods and consuming the promise they return.

For instance, if you're receiving JSON:

```
fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ albums: data }));
```

Live Example:

```js
fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

---

Or we could call the parameter `albums` and use shorthand property notation:

```
fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(albums => this.setState({ albums }));
```

Comment: Nice answer. A lot of people use axios, and that provides you with a data object, which you typically access with response.data. This will prob help a lot of people who might decide to use fetch instead.

Comment: Thanks TJ , your answer is very helpful. Can you please tell how to get response as an array?

Comment: @Arunkumar: Once parsed (by calling `.json()` and consuming the promise it returns), the JSON being returned looks like it does define an array.